# Command and variables in nested for loop

Tags: linux, bash, docker, loops, scope

I am trying to do an iterative `skopeo` copy inside a nested for loop. The command doesn't recognize the variables that I set inside the loop. I have tried:

```
for i in list_files.txt; do
  image_name=$(cat list_files.txt | sed -e 's/\-[^*]*$//')
  for i in list_files.txt; do
    version=$(cat list_files.txt | sed -e 's/[^0-9.]*//' | sed 's/.tar//')
    tar_name=$(cat list_files.txt)

    skopeo copy \
      docker-archive:/opt/app-root/src/$tar_name \
      docker://private/dsop/test/$image_name:$version \
      --dest-creds=$USERNAME:$PASSWORD \
      --dest-tls-verify=false
  done
done
```

Why can I not use the variables that I set?

I get error:

`FATA[0000] Exactly two arguments expected`

Comment: `image_name=$(cat list_files.txt | sed -e 's/\-[^*]*$//')`- do you mean for your image_name to include all image names or just one at a time? In addition, it's all but convention to always put quotation marks around variable calls, i.e. `docker-archive:/opt/app-root/src/"$tar_name"`

Comment: Put `set -x` before the section you don't understand, and it'll print out commands (or their equivalent, which can be a little confusing) as it executes them. This may clarify what's going on as it executes.

Comment: Don't read lines with for. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor this ain't Python...

Comment: Several oddities here: You have a nested loop where you use the same loop variable in both cases. This can't be right. Finally, you don't use your loop variables anywhere, so what is the point in having a loop? Finally, did you verify that `version`, `tar_name`, `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` don't contain spaces?

Comment: @swarr35 : Also get rid of the `cat`s. They are not needed and only make your program look more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Whatever reason you have to do a double for loop, you don't have any to use the same iterated variable